# Smart contract state storage under the hood and scalability

Tags: contract-development, web3js, contract-design

I know smart contract state is being added in block, Does this true always ? When I add or update an array of struct in contract what happens under the hood ? Is there any limit for such data structure ?  Will this not be going to exhausted soon ?  Block size will be very huge after years right ? Is there a scalability issue ?